DBT on top of DuckDB is working on first run but not on subsequent runs
When running my DBT code I get a first great output as such:
(.venv) jarich@Jarichs-Air peak_dbt % dbt run
10:32:56  Running with dbt=1.8.6
10:32:56  Registered adapter: duckdb=1.8.3
10:32:56  Found 2 models, 1 source, 416 macros
10:32:56  
10:32:56  Concurrency: 1 threads (target='dev')
10:32:56  
10:32:56  1 of 2 START sql view model DEV_peak.staging.stg_payments ...................... [RUN]
10:32:56  1 of 2 OK created sql view model DEV_peak.staging.stg_payments ................. [OK in 0.07s]
10:32:56  2 of 2 START sql table model DEV_peak.marts.payment_overview ................... [RUN]
10:32:56  2 of 2 OK created sql table model DEV_peak.marts.payment_overview .............. [OK in 0.18s]
10:32:56  
10:32:56  Finished running 1 view model, 1 table model in 0 hours 0 minutes and 0.44 seconds (0.44s).
10:32:56  
10:32:56  Completed successfully
10:32:56  
10:32:56  Done. PASS=2 WARN=0 ERROR=0 SKIP=0 TOTAL=2

However doing the second run results in:
(.venv) jarich@Jarichs-Air peak_dbt % dbt run
10:33:00  Running with dbt=1.8.6
10:33:00  Registered adapter: duckdb=1.8.3
10:33:00  Found 2 models, 1 source, 416 macros
10:33:00  
10:33:00  Concurrency: 1 threads (target='dev')
10:33:00  
10:33:00  1 of 2 START sql view model DEV_peak.staging.stg_payments ...................... [RUN]
10:33:00  1 of 2 ERROR creating sql view model DEV_peak.staging.stg_payments ............. [ERROR in 0.05s]
10:33:00  2 of 2 SKIP relation marts.payment_overview .................................... [SKIP]
10:33:00  
10:33:00  Finished running 1 view model, 1 table model in 0 hours 0 minutes and 0.21 seconds (0.21s).
10:33:00  
10:33:00  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
10:33:00  
10:33:00    Runtime Error in model stg_payments (models/peak/staging/stg_payments.sql)
  Catalog Error: Could not rename "stg_payments__dbt_tmp" to "stg_payments": another entry with this name already exists!
10:33:00  
10:33:00  Done. PASS=0 WARN=0 ERROR=1 SKIP=1 TOTAL=2

I am on MacOS, macbook air with M1 processor. It feels really strange to me as DBT should just overwrite the table it created in the first run, but somehow doesn't want to do that. Also added (part of) my project structure for reference.
